# wxMaxima + gnuplot = Mathematica-like densitymap with a twist

Tags: gnuplot, maxima, frequency-analysis

I would like to plot the frequency-domain response of a filter in a similar manner to how the pole-zero plots are on the Wikipedia's "Chebyshev filter" page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chebyshev_Type_I_Filter_s-Plane_Response_(8th_Order).svg . In particular, what I would like is to cut the plot in half along the Y axis and to make the cut stand out as representing the frequency response.

So far I have managed to get this:

[image]

The maked seam can be seen but it doesn't stand out, as if freshly welded. I hope the meaning gets to you because I can't find a better explanation now.

Now, what I have, so far, with wxMaxima's draw3d() function, is this:

```
draw3d(logx=false,logy=false,logz=true,
enhanced3d=false,line_width=2,color=red,explicit(cabs(Hs(x+%i*y)),x,-0.01,0,y,-3,3),
enhanced3d=[z**.5,x,y,z],palette=gray,proportional_axes=xy,
/* cbrange=[0.05,100.95], */ view=[0,0],yv_grid=101,xu_grid=101,
explicit(cabs(Hs(x+%i*y)),x,-1,0,y,-3,3))$
```

where Hs(s) is defined earlier, say:

```
Hs(s):=0.0248655/((s+0.210329)*(s^2+0.12999*s+0.521695)*(s^2+0.340319*s+0.22661))$
```

I don't know how to make the frequency response stand out, the order of printing doesn't seem to matter. Does anyone know if it can be done and, if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to achieve that with maxima, but here is a solution with gnuplot only. This uses the `+` pseudo filename to create the 1D-plot for x=0 with `splot`. Complex numbers are specified with brackets, `{x,y}`, i.e. `i = {0,1}`:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1000,800
set output 'chebyshev.png'

N = 501
set isosamples N
set samples N
set pm3d interpolate 3,3

set palette gray
set cbrange [*:10]
set xrange [-1:0]
set yrange [-3:3]

set logscale z
set autoscale zfix

set view 120,278
unset key
set grid

Hs(s) = 0.0248655/((s+0.210329)*(s**2+0.12999*s+0.521695)*(s**2+0.340319*s+0.22661))

splot abs(Hs(x+{0,1}*y)) w pm3d, \
      '+' using (y = ($0/(N-1.0) * 6 - 3), 0):(y):(abs(Hs({0,1}*y))) w l lw 3
```

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I followed your steps like a robot but, with 4.6 patchlevel 3 (from terminal), I get this: http://s28.postimg.org/oaahkt55p/chebyshev.png . There is some red in the lower left corner, but... Here're my steps:

Comment: gnuplot> set terminal pngcairo size 1000,800
Terminal type set to 'pngcairo'
Options are ' background "#ffffff" fontscale 1.0 size 1000, 800 '
gnuplot> set output 'chebyshev.png'
gnuplot> N=501
gnuplot> set isosamples N
gnuplot> set samples N
gnuplot> set pm3d interpolate 3,3
gnuplot> set palette gray
gnuplot> set cbrange [*:10]
gnuplot> set xrange [-1:0]
gnuplot> set yrange [-3:3]
gnuplot> set logscale z
gnuplot> set autoscale zfix
gnuplot> set view 120,278
gnuplot> unset key
gnuplot> set grid

Comment: gnuplot> Hs(s)=0.0248655/((s+0.210329)*(s**2+0.12999*s+0.521695)*(s**2+0.340319*s+0.22661))
gnuplot> splot abs(Hs(x+{0,1}*y)) w pm3d, \
>'+' using (y=($0/(N-1.0)*6+3),0):(y):(abs(Hs({0,1}*y))) w l lw 3
Fontconfig error: "misc.conf", line 50: invalid attribute 'name'
Fontconfig error: "misc.conf", line 59: invalid attribute 'name'
Fontconfig error: "misc.conf", line 70: invalid attribute 'name'
gnuplot>

Comment: I'm sorry for the quadruple post, hitting <enter> doesn't seem to get a new line. Also, I don't know how to add <code> here (in the comments).

Comment: The code looks fine. I just tested again with my above code, and it works fine with 4.6.3 and even 4.4.4 on Linux. Save the above code (maybe put a `reset` at the beginning) in a file `chebyshe.gp` and then just call `gnuplot chebyshev.gp` or use `load 'chebyshev.gp'` from the gnuplot prompt. I don't know if the Fontconfig error has some unexpected consequences. Maybe try a different terminal e.g. `set terminal png size 1000,800`. Does the line show up if you only use the `splot '+'...` part?

Comment: Saving it as "chebyshev.gp" and invoking 'gnuplot chebyshev.gp' from the terminal worked like a charm! I don't know why, I have never used gnuplot by itself, but I may start doing some research these days. Thank you for the solution, I'll mark this one as the good answer.